# How to display an index.html file from local disk file system in an <iframe>?

Tags: jsp, servlets, struts2

I have an `index.html` file in my local disk file system on `c:\report\index.html`. I need to display this file in web application's JSP page in an `<iframe>`.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a [servlet](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info) which gets an `InputStream` of it with help of  `FileInputStream` and writes it to the `OutputStream` of the response after having set the proper content type header (so that the browser understands how to deal with it). Finally just specify the URL of the servlet in the `<iframe src>`.

E.g.

```
@WebServlet("/reportServlet")
public class ReportServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        Inputstream input = new FileInputStream("c:/report/index.html");
        OutputStream output = response.getOutputStream();
        // Write input to output the usual way.
    }

}
```

with

```
<iframe src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/reportServlet" ...></iframe>
```

An alternative is to map `c:/report` as a new webapp context in your server configuration so that you can just access it directly by http://example.com/report/index.html.

```
<iframe src="/report/index.html" ...></iframe>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response. It worked fine for me. One more question, If index.html is having many links to some other html files(same directory) , How to handle this case ?

Comment: Well, you could let the servlet parse and manipulate the HTML to replace all links. But publishing the entire folder it as another context is more easy.

Comment: How to publish the folder as another context ? Thanks.

Comment: This has to be done by server configuration, so it depends on the server make/version used.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it simple ?

```
<IFRAME SRC="D:\\lib\\hello.html" width="400" height="200">
<!-- Alternate content for non-supporting browsers -->
</IFRAME>
```

Comment: Works only when both the webbrowser and webserver happen to run at physically the same machine (which usually isn't the case in production environment).

Comment: @BalusC: Thank You.I know this but the question was not clear. So, I answered it as example.